# How to make a button open a new window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am making a simple GUI that starts with a main menu them the user can click a button to proceed to a new window which has a picture of a keyboard and the user can press key on their keyboard to play the paino. Right now I cant figure out how to make a button that when pressed closes the main menu (labeled mainMenu()) and open the game menu (playGame).

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class mainMenu:
    def _init_(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
        self.quitButton.pack(side = LEFT)

        self.proceedButton = Button(frame, text = "Play", command = playGame)
        self.proceedButton.pack(side = LEFT)

        def playGame(self):
            frame.quit
            gameMenu()


def gameMenu(self):
    root = Tk()
    b = mainMenu(root)

    topFrame = Frame(root)
    topFrame.pack()
    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomeFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "piano.png")
    label = Label(root, image = photo)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: edit: just realized that under the playGame function it calls a function gameMenu which doesnt exist. The function below it called playGame should be called gameMenu.

Comment: So its ok now or not? Please edit question if something has changed.

Comment: No its still giving me an error that 'root' is not defined.

Comment: Root is not defined because your indentation is wrong. Check if this indentation posted here is the same as in your actual source file. Difficult to help, if indentation is your actual program is different than shown in this question.

Comment: @Marcin in my actual code all lines are indented all the way to the left but I still cant figure out how to make it look like that on here. It looks just like it does on here.

Comment: @Benjamin Root is not defined because you define root in `gameMenu()` which isn't called before `mainloop()` therefore it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to forgive me for removing your class but I've never personally worked with classes in python before. However I seem to have you code working to some degree.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

def playGame():
    frame.quit
    gameMenu()


def gameMenu():
    b = mainMenu(root)

    topFrame = Frame(root)
    topFrame.pack()
    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    photo = PhotoImage(file = "piano.png")
    label = Label(root, image = photo)
    label.pack()

root=Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

quitButton = Button(frame, text = "Quit", command = frame.quit)
quitButton.pack(side = LEFT)

proceedButton = Button(frame, text = "Play", command = playGame)
proceedButton.pack(side = LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

The main problem you had was that you were using both `root` and `master`. When declaring the main window in tkinter you normally use either `root = Tk()` or `master = Tk()` either one is acceptable, personally I use `master`. This variable contains the main window that everything else is placed into. You also hadn't put `Tk()` into any variable, meaning that when you hit `root.mainloop()` there was nothing to enter the main loop, this was because you were trying to declare `root = Tk()` inside gameMenu, which wasn't getting called in your program.

If you want to open windows within tkinter it's probably easier to write something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk() #Declaring of main window

def ProceedButtonCommand(mainframe, master): #Command to attach to proceed button
    mainframe.destroy()
    DrawSecondScreen(master) #This line is what lets the command tied to the button call up the second screen

def QuitButtonCommand(master):
    master.destroy()

def DrawFirstScreen(master):
    mainframe = Frame(master) #This is a way to semi-cheat when drawing new screens, destroying a frame below master frame clears everything from the screen without having to redraw the window, giving the illusion of one seamless transition
    ProceedButton = Button(mainframe, text="Proceed", command=lambda: ProceedButtonCommand(mainframe, master)) #Lambda just allows you to pass variables with the command
    QuitButton = Button(mainframe, text = "Quit", command=lambda: QuitButtonCommand(master))
    mainframe.pack()
    ProceedButton.pack()
    QuitButton.pack()

def DrawSecondScreen(master):
    mainframe = Frame(master)
    Label1 = Label(mainframe, text="Temp")
    mainframe.pack()
    Label1.pack()

DrawFirstScreen(master)
master.mainloop() #The mainloop handles all the events that occur in a tkinter window, from button pressing to the commands that a button runs, very important
```

This little script just draws a screen with two buttons, one draws a new screen with the text "temp" on it and the other button closes the `master` window.
In the future it's probably a better idea to ask a friend who is experienced in programming to help with this kind of stuff. Get talking on some computing forums, I'm sure you'll find a group of sharing and fixing code quickly.

Comment: If this question has been answered can you please close it